# Use of state with multiple key in react-native (multiple declarations, define as object, or use reducer?)

Tags: react-native

i have a blog-post Form with a lot of input (about 20).

I should use state in this way:

```
  const [title,setTitle] = useState('');
  const [desc,setDesc] = useState('');
  const [lang,setLang] = useState('');
  .....
  .....
```

OR in this way?

```
  const [post,setPost] = useState({title:'',desc:'',lang:'',......})
```

I thought of using a reducer (`useReducer()`), but how should my reducer function be done? like this?

```
const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update_name':
      return .....
    case 'update_desc':
      return ....
    case 'update_lang':
      return ....
    case ...**and other 17 case**.... 
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: The first way you should use

Comment: Why? in the first case if I have 20 TextInput I will have 20 declarations of useState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to stick with `useState` you should definitely use the first one. Yes, that may mean you'll have a lot of declarations of `useState`. But consider this: suppose you need to move some state up or down the component hierarchy. If they are separate, then this is easy, you just move it and pass as props. If they're all in an object that you are accessing via e.g. the dot operator, then you're going to have to remember to change the access sites. It also makes for smaller cleaner git diffs (relevant if you're a professional developer on a team).

Another reason is that unlike `setState` for class components the setter function from `useState` **does not** automatically preserve unchanged object properties:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState({ baz: 2, bar: 3 });
setFoo({ baz: 5 }); // bar is now missing!
```

So you have to remember to do this instead:

```
setFoo({ ...foo, { baz: 5 } });
```

...every single time.

If you have a large group of related properties that you want to store in an object, have a look at `useReducer` instead. I generally prefer it except in cases of local state (e.g. whether something is checked, visible, etc.). For ephemeral local component state `useState` requires less ceremony.

Comment: Thanks @Jared for your comment. I thought of using a reducer, but it seems excessive for me  define a lot of 'cases' in my reducer function just for update the values ​​in the state. 
What do you think about it?

Comment: @MichelC. I typically start with one big blob of state and a reducer and refactor to multiple reducers for related concerns once I get a better feel for how the app structure plays out. But one way to perhaps make it more palatable is this rule of thumb: no logic in reducer switch statements. The reducer should be a dispatcher only and call appropriate named functions that actually do stuff. My switch cases are all one-line returns: `switch (action.type) { case 'do-stuff': return doStuff(state); }`.